# How do I run batches of data through nn.ModuleList

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to work with PyTorch's ModuleList and train it with batches.

If I understood the usual PyTorch practice correctly, one writes the code for a given model/network using the template set below, writing a `forward` function, and PyTorch takes care of the initial batch dimension only when we run through the model doing `model(..)`.

```py
import torch as T
import torch.nn as nn

N = 10 # number of elements in ModuleList
H = 2  # input dimension
B = 5  # batch size

class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.list_of_nets = nn.ModuleList([nn.Linear(H, H) for i in range(N)])

    def forward(self, i, x):
        return self.list_of_nets[i](x)
```

However, if I try to run this on batches of data I get an error of the kind `TypeError: only integer tensors of a single element can be converted to an index`

```py
model = MyModel()
idx = T.randint(0, N, (B,))
x_input = T.rand((B, H))

# both give me the TypeError
model(idx, x_input)
model(idx.reshape(B, 1), x_input)

# this is fine, as expected
model(idx[0], x_input[0])
```

I checked that the type of my `idx` input is integer (and it does work when I take only the first datapoint), so this is not the source of the issue.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

ModuleList doesn't have anything to do with batches. Here is an example how you can use ModuleList:

```
class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layers = nn.ModuleList([
            nn.Linear(32, 64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(64, 10)
        ])
        
    def forward(self, x):
        for layer in self.layers:
            x = layer(x)
        return x
```

If you want to load your data into batches, you should use a DataLoader. Then use a for loop to load it.

Comment: If the execution was sequential (which it doesn't seem to be the case, given the random initialization of `idx`) then you would rather use an `nn.Sequential`, not `nn.ModuleList`

Comment: Yes, me too, but this is just an silly example to show how nn.ModuleList can be applied. The important thing here is the loop in forward method.

Comment: yes, the execution in my use case isn't sequential as I want to select just one of the Linear layers for each forward pass. I also have something more complex instead of simply Linear, but that is not relevant here as I was showing a MWE

Answer (score 2):

[`nn.ModuleList`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.ModuleList.html) doesn't work like that. It is essentially a *list* of `nn.Module`. As such, its `__getitem__` function expects an integer (as you did in your 3rd statement).

What you would usually encounter is the use of a list comprehension. Something like this:

```
def forward(self, i, x):
    out = torch.stack([self.list_of_nets[_i](x) for _i in i])
    return out
```

Then you can call your forward function with a tensor to index your module list:

```
>>> model(idx, x_input) # shaped (B,B,H)
```